# Do I need copyright, trademark or other registrations, to publish stories by Shakespeare?

Tags: creative-writing, publishing, legal, copyright

I have written summary and storyline of Shakespeare's plays. I need to know the process of publication, and the legal notes, on publishing synopses, where the original author is someone else.

Comment: Shakespeare is public domain. You're free to use however you wish. Other authors, IDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shakespeare's plays are in the public domain. For more recent works, such as works produced in the past 100 years, check the copyright laws of the country where you plan to publish your works and consult a lawyer. To gain background in this area, I recommend reading the Wikipedia articles on [Copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright) and [International copyright treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_copyright_treaties).